# What do I need to know to understand Lam's Serre's Problem on projective modules

Tags: reference-request

What do I need to know to understand this book: [Lam's Serre's Problem on projective modules](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=7K-h_v_JPf8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=lam%20serre&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=hAQ-U_jIEYe_0AHu_ICIDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=lam%20serre&f=false)?

I've already read [Hungerford's book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=hungerford&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=zQQ-U9qOGuOU0QGy8IDQCA&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=hungerford&f=false) and [Atiyah and Macdonald's book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=HOASFid4x18C&printsec=frontcover&dq=atiyah%20commutative&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=GAU-U7qtG4KX0AHnjoCIBQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=atiyah%20commutative&f=false), however when I started to read the first pages of the Lam's book, I was surprised with  a definition of projective modules very different I know from Hungerford's one.

My question is what I have to know to understand this book?

**EDIT**

Regarding the background needed, the author only mentions this quote: "... a good grounding in graduate level algebra is assumed." which doesn't help me very much.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Often the front matter suggests prerequisites--have you checked there?

Comment: @MPW yes, he said: "...a good grounding in graduate level algebra is assumed." It's not very clear to me what miss to me to have such a grounding.

Comment: this question would be much improved if "the book" was actually mentioned in text here not just in a link.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook is it ok now?

Comment: @user42912 yep. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to quote the book:

> "... a good grounding in graduate level algebra is assumed."

However, he introduces some commutative algebra in the first chapter.

Comment: yes, I have read this part, but what it misses to me to have this "good grounding"?

Comment: If you have read Hungerford and understood it, you should be in fine shape. I'm assuming that's his GTM text.